# For games, would you implement to security or to usability?

Tags: android, security

I plan to create a game that is largely online-based via mobiles.  I have in my mind how I would handle authentication for both a very secure standpoint (login, credential creation, etc), and also from a very usable standpoint (device authentication, client based, no action needed).

Since I am the only one in my development team (lol), I am interested to hear your input about this problem.  In my mind, I would like to implement to usability due to the lackadaisical nature of gaming, and how impressed I have been with services like scoreloop (who dont require and/or pester the user for login / password / account generation).  But it also brings a certain amount of uncertainty and lack of control to the user.

For a game, what is more important to you?  Or is there an implementation you can think of that is a marriage of the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It completely depends on what kind of game you are trying to build. If the game you are going to make is a really simple quick multiplayer game it hardly makes any sense to incorporate heavy security, just entering a name would be enough for it to be playable.

On the other hand, I don't really dislike logging in all that much, but it would be ideal if the server would just recognise my phoneID and would use that as an identification. The only problemn this would cause is that if you use another phone you would have a new useraccount.

But then again, how many people own multiple android devices they use for playing games...

Comment: For the most part I agree in your state of conflict!  As for my game, it will be an ongoing online-based game with campaigns that last a month or two, so yes, the user will be quick to access but also long-term used.  I think I may simply have initial authentication, and then build some sort of auth token based off the device ID, that would then send the credentials to the phone for future connections.  Hmm.  Much thinking to do!

Comment: What you could do is make some sort of combo? Don't do an initial login, but make an option like: link phone ID. If the user presses that in options it gets a unique token that lets it link phoneID's together.